# Uninstall (delete) iOS app from source code?

Tags: ios

On iOS devices,to uninstall app, user long press app icon until it starts wobbling with (X) symbol on top left. Once (X) is pressed, it displays "Delete app" alertview. If Delete button is pressed, it uninstall app from device.

I'd like to write an utility application which removes other unwanted applications. This will be automated so that I don't need to remove them manually.

Any suggestion or hint?

Answer (score 6):

It's not possible without the device being jailbroken. There is no access to which apps are actually on the device, much less an option to delete them.